# Python FTP (from ftplib module) fails on login to SFTP server

Tags: python

I am doing the following

```
>> from ftplib import FTP
>> s = FTP('host','user','password') # Connect
```

and it fails giving the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in  <module>
   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 117, in __init__
     self.connect(host)
   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 132, in connect
     self.sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout)
   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
     raise err socket.error: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
```

- I know that host, user, passwd are correct
- How do I debug/fix this error?

Comment: That's not a failure to login, but a failure to connect; can you reach that server using another FTP program?

Comment: Yes, it works from other programs though, like WinSCP

Comment: Do you have any firewall active?

Comment: Are you sure that you are not doing a SFTP connection with WinSCP?

Comment: winscp may be works through ssh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WinSCP (which you've otherwise been using to connect to the same server) supports SFTP and SCP, not FTP.

To write a Python program using SFTP, you should be using the [Paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) library.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this:

```
try:
    s = FTP(host)
    s.login(user, password)
except Exception, e:
    print "The error was:", str(e)
```

Comment: This won't provide anything not already included in the stack trace -- the string representation being `[Errno 60] Operation timed out`.